# What type of aircraft uses this long flashing pattern?

Tags: aircraft-identification, aircraft-lighting

5:00 am every morning I went to Rice-Field Road for a jog. I always see airplanes with flashing lights. All of them have the same flashing patterns except for the one that I just saw yesterday.

The pattern is a long flash. If I'm not mistaken (I counted it), it flash slowly for more or less 10 seconds and then gone at same count.

I was curious and surprised that there's an aircraft that has that kind of flashing patterns. I gazed at it for a minute until it was out of my sight.

I also found [this](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/9722/do-lights-on-aircraft-flash-in-a-specific-pattern) and I'm not satisfied since I'm more concerned of what type of aircraft was it.

What type of aircraft uses this long flashing pattern? References might also help. Thanks in advance :)

**UPDATED:**

This was the exact [location](https://www.google.com.ph/maps/@16.0087432,120.585176,3a,75y,359.51h,94.96t/data=!3m6!1e1!3m4!1sEeEdu6XoeqzuUZ3yUFxYaQ!2e0!7i13312!8i6656?hl=en) where I saw it.

I'm not so familiar how high or low an aircraft might be for a landing. But I guess the aircraft was too high for a landing and its direction was straight away from a landing area. And yeah, the flash was color white.

Comment: 10 seconds is *not a flash*. Could you have seen the landing lights? They are very bright when the plane is flying almost directly towards you, but not visible from other angles.

Comment: Where is "Rice-Field Road"?

Comment: Could the aircraft have been passing through clouds that obscured the lights for a period of time?

Comment: @Notts90, that's what I'm thinking before but the sky was clear that time

Answer (score 4):

I'm assuming your question is : "What type of aircraft was it?".
Actually, we can't answer your question but you could try using [Flightradar](http://www.flightradar24.com) to identify the aircraft by watching a playback of the regarding time and place.

To hand you some trivia: If it was a red flashing light (the beacon) it is totally normal that the kind of flash varies. Modern aircraft use 360 degrees flashing lights (depending on the manufacturer it flashes faster or slower). Older (and most small aircraft) use rotating beacons which is just a red light shining in one direction which is turned by an motor (turns faster or slower depending on the motor).

If it was a big white light it could possibly have been the landing lights (which flash only on some aircraft) or the strobe light in the wings outer edges. They usually flash 2 times in one second and repeat the two flashes after 1 second of pause.

Comment: IIRC the strobes _must_ flash every second. It may be two flashes very short after each other, but they would repeat _every_ second. 3-4 seconds would be incredibly sparse.

Comment: @JanHudec There are some LED strobes that flash a lot slower than the old-style xenon tubes we're used to, but almost certainly not once every 3 seconds (IIRC the FARs specify 40-100 flashes per minute).

Comment: People tend to mention the colour of lights that aren't white, so I'd assume a white light. But still good to cover the other options.