# Airliner headlights flashing alternately

Tags: safety, airliner

I live in Portland,Oregon.  I watched a large jetliner coming into the airspace heading to the airport.  The red,green and tail lights were normal. But the headlights were blinking alternately.  I have never seen that in all my years watching the sky. Is there a reason for the alternate blinking?Emergency onboard?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it unusual for an aircraft to flash its landing lights in sequence?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/35667/is-it-unusual-for-an-aircraft-to-flash-its-landing-lights-in-sequence)

Answer (score 6):

Some modern landing lights have a pulsating or alternating mode. It's just for being recognized more easily, has nothing to do with an emergency.

A constant white light heading right for you over a city full of lights doesn't get as much attention as a pulsating light which gets bigger each time as you get closer :)

Here is one example: https://www.preciseflight.com/pulselite-pulsing-aircraft-lights/

and their video:

Comment: Thanks. It just seemed unusual.

Answer (score -1):

What you were likely seeing is the [wingtip strobes](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WywlNaALMA4) which are white and flash alternatively. Aircraft don't have "headlights" per-say but they do have [landing lights](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WywlNaALMA4) which do not flash by design but can be [flashed manually](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/35667/is-it-unusual-for-an-aircraft-to-flash-its-landing-lights-in-sequence).

Comment: The proposed duplicate suggests landing lights _can_ flash. Or did I misinterpret that?

Comment: @PerlDuck landing lights can _be_ flashed manually and its possibly thats what was seen but it is also possible it was the flashing strobes which flash by design. Ill edit my answer a bit to elaborate on the landing lights needing to be flashed manually.

Comment: I edited my reply as well, I've seen many videos of aircraft that do have pulsating landing lights and no you don't have to manually flash them.