# Can fighter jets set their lights to flash six times?

Tags: military, usa, fighter, aircraft-lighting

So last night President Trump was in town at the Grand Rapids Airport in Michigan. I live about 5 miles away directly to the west of the airport. I noticed multiple high and fast flying jets (they were not on my Flightaware app). I would see them flashing 6 times quickly with about a 1-2 second pause in-between. It was very consistent. I had never seen 6 quick flashes from any jet ever. I'm hoping someone can verify which type of (I'm assuming fighter) jet can do that, and why?

Comment: Welcome to aviation.SE! [This question](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/9722/62) is closely related, and some answers to it point out that at least some military aircraft are able to use several different lighting patterns.